# How to get value outside promise function

Tags: node.js

```
public async getOfferingPricingPlan({
    offeringId
  }: GetOfferingPricingPlanOptions): Promise<GetOfferingPricingPlanResponse> {
    return this.offeringClient.getPricingPlan({
      offeringId: offeringId,
      auth: {
        asap: this.asap
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```
     let pricingPlanId;

    this.getOfferingPricingPlan({
      offeringId: mapItemToOfferingId(item),
    }).then(res=>{
      if(res.values && res.values[0] && res.values[0].key){
      return pricingPlanId = res.values[0].key;
      } else {
        throw ("Invalid ")
      }
    
    });

console.log(pricingPlanId);
```

I need pricingPlanId value outside asyn function

Answer (score 0):

Well because it's a Promise you only have the value once the promise executes.

You can add an `async` keyword to the wrapping function so you can use `await` inside.

```
async function() {

    // ...

    const pricingPlanId = await this.getOfferingPricingPlan({
      offeringId: mapItemToOfferingId(item),
    }).then(res=>{
      if(res.values && res.values[0] && res.values[0].key){
      return pricingPlanId = res.values[0].key;
      } else {
        throw ("Invalid ")
      }
    
    });

    console.log(pricingPlanId);
}
```

OR as deceze pointed out in the comments -> it's not ideal to mix .then and await, so you can drop `then` altogether:

```
async function() {
    let pricingPlanId;
    const res = await this.getOfferingPricingPlan({
      offeringId: mapItemToOfferingId(item),
    })

    if(res.values && res.values[0] && res.values[0].key){
       pricingPlanId = res.values[0].key;
    } else {
       throw ("Invalid ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `await`…?

Comment: @deceze oops, missed it. Thanks

Comment: Now you shouldn't mix `await` and `.then`. You should refactor this to get rid of the `.then` callback…

Comment: @deceze I agree it's not ideal to mix them but it's still working code. It's maybe trickier to understand but it doesn't mean it's wrong. I don't normally use it but wanted to provide a working example without too much change